# Apache And PHP Permissions

Tags: ubuntu, php, permissions, web-server, apache2

I have a server using ubuntu server, with apache2 and php.

I want to setup a directory with a php file, that is visible to the internet,and inside it, a directory that is private, and no one (apache) has access to it, except that php file.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange for PHP to execute as a different user from plain Apache, then that would be easy: you set the private directory as owned by the PHP user and permissions 700.

Alternatively, if the PHP interpreter must run as the same user as the Apache server (as usual), you can use Apache configuration directives (in a `.htaccess` file or otherwise) to specify that Apache must never serve anything from that directory. This is how to do it in the "main" Apache configuration files:

```
<Directory "/your/private/directory">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

In a `.htaccess` file, just use the `Require` line on its own:

```
Require all denied
```

It will automatically apply to the directory the `.htaccess` file is located in.

The PHP interpreter can access the filesystem without going through Apache, and so it will be able to access the private directory. Then you just set the private directory as owned by the Apache service user, and with permissions 700.

Comment: ok, i will try that

Comment: how do i write it in a .htaccess file?

Comment: In a .htaccess file, just the `Require all denied` line should be enough to block all access.

Comment: so can you edit your answer so i could accept it?